# Laravel 4 - Eloquent relationship find by username

Tags: laravel, eloquent

```
$picture = User::find(Session::get('user_id'))
         ->pictures()->where('approved', '=', '1')->first();
```

How can i modify this code according to username instead of Session::get('user_id')

Thanks.

Comment: it does not work. Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::pictures()

Comment: I think the correct way would be ```$picture = User::where('username', $username)->firstOrFail()->pictures()->where('approved', '=', '1')->first();``` in a try/catch.

Comment: Oh well nozzleman updated his answer. It'll work with his code for sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if the user is logged in, try

```
$pictures = Auth::user()->pictures()->where('approved', '1')->first();
```

**Update**

regarding your comment:

```
try {
    $pictures = User::where('name', $searchname)->firstOrFail()->pictures()->where('approved', '1')->first();
}
catch (Exception $e) {
    // stuff to do, if no user is found
}
```

Comment: i need it without auth